# How to create Zend_Db_Select with nested queries?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

I don't know if its possible but I'd like to make it a Zend_Db_Select object and I don't know how

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable MT1
WHERE MT1.date = (
     SELECT MAX(MT2.date)
     FROM MyTable MT2
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like that would work :

```
$nestedSelect = $db->select()->from(
    array('MT2' => 'MyTable'),
    new Zend_Db_Expr('MAX(MT2.date)')
);

$select = $db->select()->from(
    array('MT1', 'MyTable')
)->where(
    'MT1.date = ?', new Zend_Db_Expr('(' . $nestedSelect->toString() . ')')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also do it by simply replacing the (`$this->select()`) subquery variable in the main query (more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1341463/216084)