# How can I turn ZF ->joinLeft()s into a Subquery?

Tags: php, zend-framework, join, subquery, zend-db

How would i convert below query to sub query?
I don't want to use JOINS I want to do same through sub query. i-e **I need three subqueries out of the three joins.** How it would be possible for below query ?

```
protected $_name = 'sale_package_features';
public function getAllSalePackageFeatures(){
    $sql = $this->select()->setIntegrityCheck(false)
            ->from(array('spf' => $this->_name))
            ->joinLeft(array('sd' => 'sale_devices'),'sd.sale_device_id = spf.sale_device_id',array('sd.sale_device_name AS deviceName'))
            ->joinLeft(array('sp' => 'sale_packages'),'sp.sale_package_id = spf.sale_package_id',array('sp.sale_package_name AS packageName'))
            ->joinLeft(array('sf' => 'sale_features'),'sf.sale_feature_id = spf.sale_feature_id',array('sf.sale_feature_name AS featureName'))
            ->where('sf.parent_id != ?',0)
            ->order('spf.sale_package_feature_id ASC');
    return $sql->query()->fetchAll();
}
```

Edited :

```
SELECT
   `spf`.*, `sd`.`sale_device_name` AS `deviceName`, 
   `sp`.`sale_package_name` AS `packageName`, 
   `sf`.`sale_feature_name` AS `featureName` 
FROM `sale_package_features` AS `spf` 
LEFT JOIN `sale_devices` AS `sd` 
  ON sd.sale_device_id = spf.sale_device_id
LEFT JOIN `sale_packages` AS `sp` 
  ON sp.sale_package_id = spf.sale_package_id 
LEFT JOIN `sale_features` AS `sf` 
  ON sf.sale_feature_id = spf.sale_feature_id 
WHERE (sf.parent_id != 0) 
ORDER BY `spf`.`sale_package_feature_id` ASC
```

Comment: Use [Zend_Db_Expr](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.9/Zend_Db/Expr/Zend_Db_Expr.html).

Comment: I know i ll use this like Zend_Db_Expr($subQuery) but i just dont know how to intigrate it all

Comment: Before taking on the conversion part, it's probably worth if you line-out how you would create a subquery on it's own, so it is more clear with which part specifically you have a problem doing the conversion. Just an idea.

Comment: @hakre I just need to turn these joins into subquery

Comment: Yes, that "needs" part is pretty clear in your question. But the part "what does stop you from doing" is not. That's why I asked, maybe you can improve this a little might be helpful in getting answer. But just a suggestion, I have no clue about subquery in zendframework.

Comment: @hakre Sir the part which stops me from doing so is that I dont know how to do so and that is very clear :(

Comment: ah okay, so you don't know at all how to create a subquery with zend-framework in the first place? Maybe you know with plain SQL so you can show plain SQL examples of what you try to achieve? also sorry if I can not be of much help, I do not even know if it is possible at all in zend-framework to create a subquery.

Comment: Just seeing your edit and if you don't mind and I may suggest another comment? I see you've posted an SQL query with all those joins. Can you also - even if not correct SQL code - place below that kind of subquery you're looking for? So it's clear which part of it you want to become a subquery? I ask because there are three joins and it's not clear if you want a part of it or all as subquery there or even multiple subqueries.

Comment: @hakre Sir as there are three joins so certainly i need three sub query

Comment: You probably should write that in your question. I would say this is not common for subqueries in general, not that I have any authority about that, but I think your question will therefore benefit if you add that you need three subqueries out of the three joins.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340564/writing-a-subquery-using-zend-db this link might help you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$dbAdapter = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
$subSelect = $dbAdapter
    ->select()
    ->from( 'tablename',
        array(
            'col1_alias' => 'column1_name',
            'col2_alias' => 'column2_name',
        ))
    ->where('somefield = ?', $value_to_be_quoted);

$select = $dbAdapter
    ->select()
    ->from(array('sub_alias' => $subSelect ))
    ->where('otherfield = ?', $other_value_to_be_quoted);

$sql = $select->assemble();
```

`$sql` will contain

```
SELECT 
    sub_alias . *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        tablename.column1_name AS col1_alias,
            tablename.column2_name AS col2_alias
    FROM
        tablename
    WHERE
        (somefield = 'quoted_value')) AS sub_alias
WHERE
    (otherfield = 'quoted_other_value')
```

If you need to use `SELECT .. WHERE x IN (subselect)` than go with

```
$select->where( 'column IN (?)', new Zend_Db_Expr($subselect->assemble()) );
```